# Form based authentication using ADFS in .net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, adfs, adfs2.0, adfs3.0

I'm very new to ADFS. My client wants to use ADFS for authentication for the web application which we are building. I have gone through many article on Form based authentication using ADFS, but i was not able to connect the dots. I still have some  open questions. To understand it clearly i'm posting some question here. Please note that, all i'm referring below are with respect to ADFS.

1. Is claim based application and forms based application are different.
2. In form based application, Does ADFS provides login page to authenticate?
3. Can we have custom login form in Form based authentication? If so how the username , password sent over to ADFs
4. Share the nice article if you have gone through so far which answers my all the above query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Claims based applications use an IDP (Identity Provider) e.g. ADFS to authenticate. In other words, the authentication is outsourced from the application. A SAML token is returned which contains the claims. Claims are attributes from an Identity repository e.g. AD.

FBA is one of the ways the IDP authenticates.

2. Yes
3. No

Comment: For third option you are saying No. But i see service now login page uses custom login page that used ADFS to authenticate.How it is possible then?

Comment: What's the link for that? If by custom you mean UI changes, then yes. If you mean your own form, then no.

Comment: @PaRsH, about your third question. ADFS provides login page for entering your credentials and you can change this page by using powershell. You can find useful information in the following link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/ad-fs-user-sign-in-customization)

Comment: @PaRsH, I am very new to adfs integration. I wanted to integrate one of my portal to one of my client for authentication at clients end. Can you share the sample of code or guide me?

Comment: @MartinKostovski, I am very new to adfs integration. I wanted to integrate one of my portal to one of my client for authentication at clients end. Can you share the sample of code or guide me?

Comment: @nzpcmad, I am very new to adfs integration. I wanted to integrate one of my portal to one of my client for authentication at clients end. Can you share the sample of code or guide me?

Comment: Hello @Mohan, you can refer to this link according to your requirement. http://developers.de/blogs/armin_kalajdzija/archive/2016/10/06/how-to-implement-web-sign-on-with-adfs-in-asp-net-mvc-using-owin.aspx. All the best